# How to code an image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I code an image slider similar to the [Nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)? Must be in Javascript/Jquery.

I want to learn and create my own solution, so I dont want any plugins suggested for this reason.

Is there any advice any one can give me, i.e. what should I do not do? starting points etc? If anyone knows of any good tutorials that would be good. Helpful tutorials though only, not the ones that just tell you to download the source code at the end of a load of jumble.

One way I thought of doing it was to insert all the images into divs, and hiding all those divs, and one by one unhiding those divs and sliding them in.

Comment: I'd suggest studying some of the plugins. There's lots of very specific code in them that won't apply to you. But you can get different approaches for the same the problem and the decide which is best for your needs.

Comment: Nivo is a very "hardcore" plugin. All the effects are built up from many divs with absolute-posisiton and multiple effects. You could try to inspect the source-code in f.eks jQuery.Cycle (which in my opinion in a great plugin).

Answer (score 3):

http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/25-must-learn-slider-tutorials-with-jquery/

http://designmodo.com/image-slider-jquery-css3/

and

http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+create+slider

good luck

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this :

```
// create an array of images (borrowed from Nivo Slider site)
var images = ["http://nivo.dev7studios.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/nemo.png", "http://nivo.dev7studios.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/walle.png", "http://nivo.dev7studios.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/toystory.png"];

// some variables
var imgNum = 0;
var imgLength = images.length - 1;

// function to change images
function changeImage(direction) {
    // get next image number
    imgNum = imgNum + direction;
    // make sure we loop
    if (imgNum > imgLength) {
        imgNum = 0;
    }
    if (imgNum < 0) {
        imgNum = imgLength;
    }
    // change the src attribute of the image
    document.getElementById('slideshow').src = images[imgNum];
    return false; // prevent default link
}

// call changeImage function on interval (3 seconds here)
window.setInterval(function() {
    changeImage(1);
}, 3000);​
```

**[Simple working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/sEBmg/)**

Im sure there are ways to improve and extend this code - this is a simple example of an image slider with next / previous buttons and a timer. And effects are a whole different ball game - I suggest you look at the source for Nivo Slider

### Update - preloading ....

I have added a `div` at the bottom of the image with the images preloaded, then hidden them using `display:none` css attribute [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/sEBmg/1/).

You could create this hidden `div` using JavaScript quite easily :

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= imgLength; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = images[i];
        document.getElementById('preload').appendChild(img);
    }
}​
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/sEBmg/2/)